# Try to remove/add class for each element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to remove a class from a specific element and add another depends on window width by using  JS. I wrote the code below but it won't work.

```
jQuery(function($) {
          var facebook = (".fa-facebook-square");
          var twitter = (".fa-twitter-square");
          var social = [facebook, twitter];
          if ($(window).width() < 768 ) {
                for (var i = 0; i < social.length; i++) {
                  var $socialCon = "$" + "('" + i + "')";
                  $socialCon.removeClass('fa-5x');
                  $socialCon.addClass('fa-4x');
                }
              }
        });
```

Comment: what's the intention? you can probably achieve whatever styles you want here with pure CSS via a media query: `@media only screen and (min-width: 768px)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first try to understand how JavaScript and jQuery work. There are many great sites with resources on the internet.

```
$(function() {
  if ($(window).width() < 768) {
    $(".fa-facebook-square, .fa-twitter-square")
        .removeClass('fa-5x')
        .addClass('fa-4x');
  }
});
```

Comment: thank you for structure. I am studying right now, so I hope in nearest future I would not ask questions like that. 

By the way, your code starts working for me after I change your `(window.width < 768)` to `$(window).width()`

Comment: I didn't mean to sound impolite, but what you're trying to do requires a certain understanding of the topic. Maybe you are a step ahead.

Comment: I am really appreciate your help)) Thank you, my problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Instaid of manupulating the element class using JavaScript it would be better to simply add your CSS rules using media query. More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

```css
#msg {
  background-color: yellow;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  #msg {
    background-color: green;
  }
}
```

```html
<span id="msg">Green background if screen is at least 768px in width, yellow if not.</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to add styles, then I'd suggest using a media query where you can target the class `fa-4x` with a stronger chain of selectors, if needed. [How CSS selectors work:](https://css-tricks.com/how-css-selectors-work/)

You could use something like so:

```
.fa-5x {
    background-color: #000000;
    padding: 40px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .fa-twitter-square.fa-4x {
        background-color: #ff0000;
        padding: 0 20px 0;
    }
}
```

If you really want to use JS then you can do something like above:

```
$(function() {
    var width = window.innerWidth;
    if (width < 768) {
        $(".fa-facebook-square, .fa-twitter-square")
            .removeClass('fa-5x')
            .addClass('fa-4x');
    }
});
```

If you need to watch for resizing in case you need a responsive site you will need to wait for any resize event and then call a function to do what you want.

```
var over767px = function() {
    var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
    if (windowWidth > 767) {
        //perform tablet/desktop code here
    } else if (windowWidth < 768) {
        //perform mobile code here
    }
};

var debouncer = function( func , timeout ) {
    var timeoutID , timeout = timeout || 50;
    return function () {
        var scope = this , args = arguments;
        clearTimeout( timeoutID );
        timeoutID = setTimeout( function () {
            func.apply( scope , Array.prototype.slice.call( args ) );
        } , timeout );
    };
};

$( window ).resize( debouncer( function ( e ) {
    over767px();
}));
```